# Where does Meteor store its copy of node?

Tags: meteor

When I open a Terminal window and run `meteor node -v` the output is `v12.16.1`. When I run `sudo find / -type f -executable -name "node" -print | grep 12` I get:

```
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/local/n/versions/node/12.6.0/bin/node
/home/blackslate/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node
```

There's no mention of 12.**16**. So where does Meteor hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node versions are inside of each meteor version is installed in your computer.

Normally these versions are in your home inside folder .meteor , not in .meteor of projects.

In my case, a mac, the folder is:

`/Users/myname/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.10.1/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin`

Comment: Yes! When I run `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.10.1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node -v`, I get the answer `v12.16.1`

Comment: And `1.10.1` is just a symbolic link to the much more verbosely named `.1.10.1.wy1wpr.rfnj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova`

Answer (score 1):

You can also "ask" node where it is by using it's execPath:

```sh
$ meteor node # runs a new repl
console.log(process.execPath)
```

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/process.html#process_process_execpath

Comment: this is a better answer because the path can change from version to version....